# How to scroll the content in the left and right direction on hitting an arrow in mobile view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, css-shapes

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wzgsobz/6/embedded/result) which is working in a way that when I take it in the mobile view, the square boxes horizontally scroll.

The CSS codes which I have used for that are:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
.product-all-contents
{
   overflow-x: auto;
}

.product-contents .product{
  min-width: 50.795%;
  margin: 0 2%;
  padding-top: 3.91%;
  padding-left: 3.91%;    
  padding-right: 3.91%;
  }
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the fiddle so that **when I hit arrows in the mobile view (as shown in the screenshot below marked by orange arrow sign)** the content move towards the left and vice-versa.

I think best solution will be **jQuery, scrollLeft() and scrollRight()** but I am not sure how I can implement it in the fiddle.

[image]

Comment: Like a carousel or a "scroll until you let go"? Need more of a picture of what you want.

Comment: Carousel will work best for me.

Comment: @Phix something like [this](http://shouldiuseacarousel.com/) or close to that.

Comment: [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) is great if you have jQuery.

Comment: @Phix I am wondering how can I implement it in the fiddle ?

Comment: I dont see the arrows in the fiddle. Have you add them?

Comment: @GerardoBLANCO I haven't added them. I am just confused how to proceed. Can you give me a pointer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem you need a few things

1. Set two buttons to set the listeners in your code
2. Get the initial position so you can calculate the slide

   let divMain = $('.product-all-contents')[0];
     let position = $(divMain).children().position().left;
     const slideAmount = 150;

This 3 variables will be the main values for the code

3. Last make the listenes for the slide

   $('#arrow-right').click(function() {
       $(divMain).animate({
         scrollLeft: position + slideAmount
       }, 500);
       position += slideAmount;
     })

Hope this helps :>

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let divMain = $('.product-all-contents')[0];
  let position = $(divMain).children().position().left;
  const slideAmount = 150;

  $('#arrow-right').click(function() {
    $(divMain).animate({
      scrollLeft: position + slideAmount
    }, 500);
    position += slideAmount;
  })

  $('#arrow-left').click(function() {
    $(divMain).animate({
      scrollLeft: position - slideAmount
    }, 500);
    position -= slideAmount;
  })
});
```

```css
.product-all-contents {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 70%;
  margin: auto;
}

.product-contents {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.product-contents .product {
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(145, 147, 150);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px
}

.ipads {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.tvs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.franchise-hub-text,
.cloud-based-text,
.business-analytics-text,
.tech-support-text,
.order-management-text,
.employee-management-text,
.white-label-text,
.brand-label-text,
.lead-tracking-text,
.custom-invoicing-text,
.goal-setting-text,
.customization-tools-text,
.royalty-calculator-text,
.email-marketing-text {
  width: 50%;
}

div.goal-setting,
div.customization-tools,
div.custom-invoicing,
div.lead-tracking,
div.email-marketing,
div.royalty-calculator,
div.brand-control,
div.franchisehubtv,
div.cloudbasedtextipad,
div.business-analytics,
div.tech-support,
div.employee-management,
div.order-management,
div.white-label {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
}

.product-quotes {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 11px;
  width: 90%;
  color: #3b3b3d;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  line-height: 1.625;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: normal;
  "

}

.arrow-down {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: auto;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  border-top: 40px solid #f0f0f0;
}

.white {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .product-all-contents {
    overflow-x: auto;
  }
  .product-contents .product {
    min-width: 50.795%;
    margin: 0 2%;
    padding-top: 3.91%;
    padding-left: 3.91%;
    padding-right: 3.91%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  div.goal-setting,
  div.customization-tools,
  div.custom-invoicing,
  div.lead-tracking,
  div.email-marketing,
  div.royalty-calculator,
  div.brand-control,
  div.franchisehubtv,
  div.cloudbasedtextipad,
  div.business-analytics,
  div.tech-support,
  div.employee-management,
  div.order-management,
  div.white-label {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .franchise-hub-text,
  .cloud-based-text,
  .business-analytics-text,
  .tech-support-text,
  .order-management-text,
  .employee-management-text,
  .white-label-text,
  .brand-control-text,
  .lead-tracking-text,
  .custom-invoicing-text,
  .goal-setting-text,
  .customization-tools-text,
  .royalty-calculator-text,
  .email-marketing-text {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Testing</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="sample.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script/myscript.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="product-all-contents">
    <div class="product-contents">
      <div class="product" id="franchisehub">

        <p style=" font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Roboto'; margin-left: 7%; margin-right: 7%; line-height: 1.2; margin-top: 20%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);">A</p>
      </div>

      <div class="product" id="cloudbasedmobile" style="background-color:#81bf44;">

        <p style=" font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';line-height:1.2; margin-top: 27%;
         color:white;">Z</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product" id="businessanalytics">

        <p style=" font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';line-height:1.2; margin-top: 22%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);">B</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product" id="techsupport">

        <p style=" font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         margin-right: 9%;
         line-height: 1.2;
         margin-left: 9%; margin-top: 22%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);">C</p>
      </div>

      <div class="product" id="ordermanagement">

        <p style=" font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';line-height:1.2; margin-top: 23%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);">D</p>
      </div>

      <div class="product" id="employeemanagement">
        <p style=" font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';line-height:1.2; margin-left: 5%; margin-top: 27%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);">E</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product" id="whitelabel">
        <p style="
         font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         line-height:1.2;
         margin-left: 14%;
         margin-right: 14%; margin-top: 8%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);
         ">M</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-contents">
      <div class="product" id="brandcontrol">

        <p style="
         font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         margin-left: 8%;
         line-height:1.2;
         margin-right: 8%; margin-top: 20%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);
         ">F</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product" id="leadtracking">

        <p style="
         font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         line-height:1.2;
         margin-left: 5%;
         margin-right: 5%; margin-top: 26%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);
         ">G</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product" id="custominvoicing">

        <p style=" font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';line-height:1.2; margin-top: 24%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);">K</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product" id="goalsetting">

        <p style="font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         margin-right: 13%;
         margin-left: 13%;
         line-height: 1.2; margin-top: 24%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);">H</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product" id="customizationtools">

        <p style=" font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';line-height:1.2; margin-top: 22%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);">I</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product" id="royaltycalculator">

        <p style=" font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';line-height:1.2; margin-left: 5%; margin-top: 23%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);">J</p>
      </div>
      <div class="product" id="emailmarketing">

        <p style="
         font-size: 15px;
         font-family: 'Roboto';
         margin-left: 5%;
         margin-right: 5%;
         line-height:1.2; margin-top: 21%;
         color: rgb(58, 59, 60);
         ">K</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




  <button id="arrow-left">&#60----</button>

  <button id="arrow-right">----&#62</button>








</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The first thing, I need to setup is an image for the arrows button.

Comment: That would be the best way to go

Comment: will catch you soon.

Comment: Perfect, 
Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers, and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation).

Comment: So, I am able to place the arrows in the mobile view. Its not visible in the desktop view. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wzgsobz/45/embedded/result) I am wondering what changes I should I make in the fiddle now so `that 4 square boxes are visible in one go when the page load and when I hit right arrow button, 4 square boxes are visible again`.

Comment: You need to adjust the squares widths and the ``slideAmount`` constant in the code

Comment: Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wzgsobz/48/embedded/result) The scroll (with left and right arrow) is working very slow here but I am able to show up in the mobile view which was my requirement. I am wondering what changes I need to make now so that if I hit on arrows, I can see good amount of speed in the horizontal scroll.

Comment: Well it is all in the combination of the ``slideAmount`` and the timer for the animate function

Comment: I am going to accept your answer. I will let you know if I have any question.

Comment: Perfect, Ill be here. Thank you

Comment: hi, I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839233/line-break-in-html-table/50839358?noredirect=1#comment88682544_50839358) related to HTML. table. Although, I have received an answer. In the question, I have replicated a particular design. **The design is basically an email sent to the user so for that I have written HTML emails**.  I have never coded HTML emails before so I am wondering if that is the right way to code html emails. Here is sample [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyc8uhg2/13/embedded/result)

Comment: Never done emails before, cant help you with that one

Comment: hey, I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50959176/aligning-data-cell-elements-in-table-in-html-email) related to table in html. Can you help me ?

Comment: Looks like you all ready got an answer. Intead of having to look for old comments you can contact me via email and I would love to help you if needed: blancogerardo94@gmail.com. Code On !

Comment: sure will do that !