# Line break in html table

Tags: css, html-table, html-email, line-breaks

I have a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyc8uhg2/2/embedded/result) which I have replicated from a particular design.

The section of the screenshot I have attached below in the problem statement.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the fiddle so that I am able to give the **line break between the following lines as shown in the screenshot** which is the **present in the fiddle** as well.

[image]

The snippets of HTML codes which I have used in the fiddle for the above lines are:

```
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">when:</td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">March 28/18 @ 7:00pm to March 30/18 @ 7:00pm</td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: It might be easier to add in a table in the first td and space things out in that? CSS in the head dont work the way it should in all email clients. Are you inlining it?

Comment: @Syfer Yes, I am doing inline-styling as for coding HTML emails, we do inline only. Can you update in the fiddle ? Here is the most updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyc8uhg2/13/embedded/result)

Comment: Posted it as an answer for you to have a look at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I have done:

Add `line-break` class to the specified `<td>`

You can use `word-wrap: break-word;` to multiline text in a div.
`word-wrap` works based on the `width` of the div.

```css
.line-break {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>


<p style="font-size:20px;margin-left:22%;color:#55BEC7;"> hi XYZ, </p>

<table style="width:100%;display: flex;
  justify-content: center;">
  
 <tbody style="font-size:20px;padding-left: 15%;"> 
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">type:</td>
 <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">availability check request</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">estimated total:</td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">$250.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">what</td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">chainsaw</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">how many</td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">when:</td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;" class="line-break">March 28/18 @ 7:00pm to March 30/18 @ 7:00pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">who:</td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;color:#FF8D58;">John s</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



<h2 style="text-align:center;color:#484848;margin-top:2.5%;margin-bottom:5%;">steps to earn your money:</h2>
<div class="steps" style="text-align: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    margin-right: auto;color:#484848;font-size:20px;">
<p>1. click here to open the ABC app to the posting requests page </p>
<p>2. click on availability check request</p>
<p>3. say yes, its availabile ot suggest another date it is</p>
<p>4. wait the 1 or 24 hour confirmation good</p>
<p>5. three days after the booking ends money will be send to your account</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyc8uhg2/11/)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am wondering if you can update it in the fiddle. In that way, it will be more easy to visualize.

Comment: @user5447339 added fiddle link

Comment: @user5447339 Whenever you go to fiddle. `CTRL-F`, paste `class="line-break"` and it'll direct you to the class I inserted.

Comment: I am wondering are your familiar with coding html emails ? I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyc8uhg2/13/embedded/result). I have used your CSS codes as an inline styling.

Comment: @user5447339 What do you mean by _coding html emails_?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173080/discussion-between-alex-and-user5447339).

Answer (score 1):

I know this question has been answered but here is an alternative way this can be approached.

Note: I have added to your code to show an example of before an after.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syfer/3anq7tcL/1/) of the same code if you need it.

```html
<html>
<body>


<p style="font-size:20px;margin-left:22%;color:#55BEC7;"> hi XYZ, </p>

<!-- new way -->
<table style="width:100%;">
 <tbody> 
  <tr>
    <td>
        <table style="width:100%;">
         <tbody> 
          <tr>
           <td width="50%" align="right" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;color:#000000;;padding:0px 20px;">type </td>
           <td width="50%" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;color:#000000;text-align:left;padding:0px 10px;">availability check request</td>
         </tr>
           
          <tr>
           <td width="50%" align="right" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;color:#000000;;padding:0px 20px;">type </td>
           <td width="50%" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;color:#000000;text-align:left;padding:0px 10px;">availability check request</td>
         </tr>
           
          <tr>
           <td width="50%" align="right" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;color:#000000;;padding:0px 20px;">type </td>
           <td width="50%" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;color:#000000;text-align:left;padding:0px 10px;">availability check request</td>
         </tr>
         </tbody>
        </table>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- new way -->

<table style="width:100%;display: flex;
  justify-content: center;">
  
 <tbody style="font-size:20px;padding-left: 15%;"> 
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">type:</td>
 <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">availability check request</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">estimated total:</td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">$250.00</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">what</td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">chainsaw</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">how many</td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;">2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">when:</td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 300px;" >March 28/18 @ 7:00pm to March 30/18 @ 7:00pm</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;text-align:right;">who:</td>
    <td style="padding-bottom: 3%;padding-left: 10%;color:#FF8D58;">John s</td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



<h2 style="text-align:center;color:#484848;margin-top:2.5%;margin-bottom:5%;">steps to earn your money:</h2>
<div class="steps" style="text-align: left;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding-right: 0%;
    margin-right: auto;color:#484848;font-size:20px;">
<p>1. click here to open the ABC app to the posting requests page </p>
<p>2. click on availability check request</p>
<p>3. say yes, its availabile ot suggest another date it is</p>
<p>4. wait the 1 or 24 hour confirmation good</p>
<p>5. three days after the booking ends money will be send to your account</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers

Comment: you have used table inside table ? Is it the right way to approach ?

Comment: The reason why I am asking because I haven't coded html emails before. Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/nyc8uhg2/13/embedded/result) not the preferred way ?

Comment: The code which is present in my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nyc8uhg2/13/embedded/result) is the 1st time I have wrote it.

Comment: You can use nested tables. It is recommended. It's not a matter of preference, it has to be tested to see how it works in different email clients. Outlook for example will give passing on both TD's inside sibling tr's. So it's best to have nested tables. Advantage: you have total control. Disadvantage: code will increase slightly.

Comment: Perfectly makes sense @Syfer, I will let you know if I have any questions.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say padding _Outlook for example will give **padding** on both TD's inside sibling tr's. So it's best to have nested tables._